# Getting an error with a shop GUI in roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I have this shop gui in roblox that keeps giving me an error when I try and buy something. I have the link to the model so you can look at it and try and solve the problem. This is the code where things are going wrong

```
local price = script.Parent.Parent.Price
local tools = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Tools")
local tool = tools:FindFirstChild(script.Parent.Parent.ItemName.Value)
local player = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    if player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Coins").Value >= price.Value then -- Change "Money" to the name of your currency. Example: Cash
        player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Coins").Value = player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Coins").Value - price.Value
        local clone = tool:Clone()
        clone.Parent = player.Backpack
        -- Copy this code if you want the player to still have the tool even if he died
        local clone2 = tool:Clone()
        clone2.Parent = player.StarterGear
    end
end)
```

This is the error it gives me.

10:16:49.715 - Players.kaitheawsomecathoo1.PlayerGui.Shop.Frame.Info.Buy.Script:9: attempt to index nil with 'Clone'
10:16:49.715 - Stack Begin
10:16:49.715 - Script 'Players.kaitheawsomecathoo1.PlayerGui.Shop.Frame.Info.Buy.Script', Line 9
10:16:49.716 - Stack End

Any help would be great! If you need me to be more specific on anything then just let me know!

Here is the link to the model

https://www.roblox.com/library/1855829220/Shop-Gui-2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tool` is `nil`.

Find out why and only call `tool:Clone()` if tool is a valid value.

Comment: Tool is not a valid tool. So do I need to call a different tool every time I want a different tool?

Comment: `tool` is a nil value, you have to check wether it is nil befor you index it